# Modifying the Learning Rate in the middle of the Model Training in Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, language-model, gpt-2

Below is the code to configure [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/trainer.html#trainingarguments) consumed from the [HuggingFace transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) library to finetune the [GPT2](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html) language model.

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./gpt2-language-model", #The output directory
        num_train_epochs=100, # number of training epochs
        per_device_train_batch_size=8, # batch size for training #32, 10
        per_device_eval_batch_size=8,  # batch size for evaluation #64, 10
        save_steps=100, # after # steps model is saved
        warmup_steps=500,# number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
        prediction_loss_only=True,
        metric_for_best_model = "eval_loss",
        load_best_model_at_end = True,
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        learning_rate=0.00004, # learning rate
    )

early_stop_callback = EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience  = 3)
    
trainer = Trainer(
        model=gpt2_model,
        args=training_args,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=test_dataset,
        callbacks = [early_stop_callback],
 )
```

The **number of epochs** as **100** and **learning_rate** as **0.00004** and also the **early_stopping** is configured with the patience value as **3**.

The model ran for **5/100** epochs and noticed that the difference in loss_value is negligible. The latest checkpoint is saved as `checkpoint-latest`.

Now Can I modify the `learning_rate` may be to `0.01` from `0.00004` and resume the training from the latest saved checkpoint - `checkpoint-latest`? Doing that will be efficient?

Or to train with the new `learning_rate` value should I start the **training** from the beginning?

Comment: I have a similar situation, where the model is converging but *very* slowly, so I'd like to try continuing from a checkpoint with a higher learning rate. I'm also using the Trainer, which wraps things up in a way that makes it less obvious to me how to adjust the lr. How did you wind up doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you don't have to restart your training.**

Changing the learning rate is like changing how big a step your model take in the **direction determined by your loss function**.

You can also think of it as transfer learning where the model has **some experience** (no matter how little or irrelevant) and the `weights` are in a state **most likely better than a randomly initialised one**.

As a matter of fact, changing the learning rate mid-training is considered an art in deep learning and you should change it if you have a **very very good reason** to do it.

You would probably want to write down when (why, what, etc) you did it if you or someone else wants to "reproduce" the result of your model.

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch provides several methods to adjust the learning_rate:  torch.optim.lr_scheduler.
Check the docs for usage https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate

Comment: the question is related to modifying the learning_rate in the middle of the training.